# In a Visual Studio Add-In, how to disable menu items during a build?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-addins, envdte

When you write a VS addin that proffers menu items to VS, it calls your `QueryStatus` implementation to check whether your menu items should be visible, enabled, etc.

My menu items are not appropriate to run during certain situations, e.g. when a build is happening. How do I detect whether there's a build running?

Comment: The other side of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18791960/in-a-visual-studio-add-in-how-to-disable-build-while-my-code-is-operating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the [`VsShellUtilities.IsSolutionBuilding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.vsshellutilities.issolutionbuilding.aspx) method. An example of using it can be found the Managed Package Framework for Visual Studio 2010 (MPFProj10) in the [`ProjectNode`](https://github.com/sharwell/MPFProj10/blob/master/Dev10/Src/CSharp/ProjectNode.cs) class:

```
protected internal virtual bool IsCurrentStateASuppressCommandsMode()
{
    if (VsShellUtilities.IsSolutionBuilding(this.Site))
    {
        return true;
    }

    DBGMODE dbgMode = VsShellUtilities.GetDebugMode(this.Site) & ~DBGMODE.DBGMODE_EncMask;
    if (dbgMode == DBGMODE.DBGMODE_Run || dbgMode == DBGMODE.DBGMODE_Break)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```